# Getting the access time of a file/image on Windows 7 to prove/disprove file/image access

Tags: windows-7, windows

Would there have to be a definite date/time stamp on Windows 7 for it to show that I have accessed an file/image at a certain date/time?

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable it first, before it's being logged. It won't work for the past if you had not enabled it.

To enable it follow these steps:

1. open your **Start menu** (press your windows-key) and enter **cmd**
2. right-click the cmd entry and choose **Run as administrator**
3. add the following to the black window which came up

   fsutil behavior set disablelastaccess 0
4. restart your PC (it might also work without rebooting)

Now you will find the access date in the file properties.

For a better overview I'd suggest you to change the view of your folder to details. Right-click the **top bar** within your folder (where it says "Name", "Date", "Size" etc.) and choose **More**.

Now look for the option **Date accessed** and mark it. Press Ok and you will find a new bar on the details page with all dates accessed.

Please remember - this won't work for the past! It will log your actions from the moment you've set "disablelastaccess" to 0.

To **disable** the **last access logging**, take the steps above and at point 3 you enter the following:

```
fsutil behavior set disablelastaccess 1
```

**edit** this relies on the system time obviously!

Comment: The OP should note that this relies on the system time, which is easily altered. Presumably a virus scan (etc) and even a directory listing (thumbnail.db) would trigger an access time update.

Answer (score 0):

can it be this simple?  windows explored, details view, right-click in the header column, choose 'more', put a check beside DATE ACCESSED, and you will see column of dates for DATE ACCESSED...